# How to prove that $2^a (2 \cdot b+1) \ne 2^c (2 \cdot d+1)$ when $a<c$ but $b>d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no clue on how to prove that for: $a < c$ **and** $b>d$ we get:
$2^a (2 \cdot b+1) \ne 2^c (2 \cdot d+1)$

when $a,b,c,d$ are elements of $N_0 = \left \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, \ldots \right \}$ Natural numbers union with $\left \{ 0 \right \}$.

Please, is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are equal, then, dividing by $2^a$, we have an odd   number equal to an even number.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by contradiction, assume they are equal, work your way from there to a false. I ended up with d*2^(c-a+1)+2^(c-a) = 2*b+1, which obviously can't be true, because you would have 2 dividing both 2*b and 2*b+1.

Comment: would post all my steps but it's getting pretty late here.